# Why doesn't java have .field and .method reflection keywords like .class?

Tags: java, reflection, methods, field, keyword

Let's say we have this class:

```
public abstract class A {
  int x;
  public int foo();
  public int foo(int x);
}
```

As we all know, `A.class` has a distinct advantage over `Class.forName("A")`: it will still work if the name of `A` is changed by refactoring or obfuscation.

However, there is no way to get this advantage with fields and methods.  Have you ever wished that you could do this: *(see a better proposed syntax in the edit below!)*

```
Field xField = A.x.field;
Method fooMethod = A.foo().method;
Method fooIntMethod = A.foo(int).method;
```

Instead of this?

```
Field xField = A.getField("x");
Method fooMethod = A.getMethod("foo");
Method fooIntMethod = A.getMethod("foo", int.class);
```

So here's my question: does anyone know if this feature has been planned or discussed or if Sun/Oracle specifically decided against it for some reason?

**EDIT:** How about this syntax?  It avoids problems people have mentioned:

```
Field xField = A..x;
Method fooMethod = A..foo();
Method fooIntMethod = A..foo(int);
```

**Example use case**

I recently created an `AbstractTableModel` class called `EasyTableModel` that allows you to define your own POJO row type.  Its `getValueAt(...)` and `setValueAt(...)` etc. use reflection to get/set the values of the fields in the POJO.

```
public class EasyTableModel<T> extends AbstractTableModel {
    private RowFormat<T>                prototypeFormat;

    private final ArrayList<T>          rows                = new ArrayList<T>();

    ...

    public static interface RowFormat<T> {
        Object getValueAt(T row, int columnIndex);

        void setValueAt(T row, Object value, int columnIndex);

        ...
    }

    ...

    public static class ReflectionRowFormat<T> implements RowFormat<T> {
        private Field[]             fields;

        ...

        public Object getValueAt(T row, int column) {
            try {
                return fields[column].get(row);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }

        public void setValueAt(T row, Object value, Field field) {
            if (!field.getDeclaringClass().isInstance(this)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("field is not a member of this class");
            }
            setValueAt(row, value, getColumnIndex(field));
        }

        ...
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return getRowFormat(rowIndex).getValueAt(rows.get(rowIndex), columnIndex);
    }

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        getRowFormat(rowIndex).setValueAt(rows.get(rowIndex), aValue, columnIndex);
        fireTableRowsUpdated(rowIndex, rowIndex);
    }

    public void fireTableCellUpdated(T row, String columnName) {
        fireTableCellUpdated(row, indexOfColumn(columnName));
    }

    public void fireTableCellUpdated(T row, Field field) {
        fireTableCellUpdated(row, indexOfColumn(field));
    }
}
```

Using this base class, it's extremely easy to create your table:

```
public abstract class QuoteMonitorTableModel<R extends QuoteMonitorTableModel<R>.Row> extends EasyTableModel<R> {
    ...

    protected static final String   NUM_QUOTES_RECEIVED = "# Quotes Received";
    protected static final String   LAST_QUOTE_TIME     = "Last Quote Time";

    public class Row {
        public Row() {

        }

        @ColumnName(NUM_QUOTES_RECEIVED)
        private Integer numQuotesReceived;

        @ColumnName(LAST_QUOTE_TIME)
        private Long    lastQuoteTimeMillis;

        public Integer getNumQuotesReceived() {
            return numQuotesReceived;
        }

        public void setNumQuotesReceived(Integer numQuotesReceived) {
            this.numQuotesReceived = numQuotesReceived;
            fireTableCellUpdated((R) this, NUM_QUOTES_RECEIVED);
        }

        public Long getLastQuoteTimeMillis() {
            return lastQuoteTimeMillis;
        }

        public void setLastQuoteTimeMillis(Long lastQuoteTimeMillis) {
            this.lastQuoteTimeMillis = lastQuoteTimeMillis;
            fireTableCellUpdated((R) this, LAST_QUOTE_TIME);
        }
    }
}
```

What are the advantages of all this?

- You can set contents of the table through your own POJO row class without
  having to worry about column indices
- Using your own POJO row class to set values is type-safe, unlike `getValueAt(...)` and `setValueAt(...)`
- You could easily create a table using some prexisting POJO class for the row format

If you think this is an abuse of reflection, then you would consider many well-used libraries like Google GSON as an abuse of reflection as well.

Now, notice how the derived class indicates which field has changed when firing events by a String, rather than the Field:

```
    public void setNumQuotesReceived(Integer numQuotesReceived) {
        this.numQuotesReceived = numQuotesReceived;
        fireTableCellUpdated((R) this, NUM_QUOTES_RECEIVED);
    }
```

It would be nice if we could just use the fields.  But doing it with getDeclaredField() would suck:

```
public void setNumQuotesReceived(Integer numQuotesReceived) {
    this.numQuotesReceived = numQuotesReceived;
    try {
        // what if obfuscation changes the name of the numQuotesReceived field?
        fireTableCellUpdated((R) this, getClass().getDeclaredField("numQuotesReceived"));
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
    }
}
```

However, with the feature I am proposing, it would be easy as cake:

```
public void setNumQuotesReceived(Integer numQuotesReceived) {
    this.numQuotesReceived = numQuotesReceived;
    // if obfuscation changes the name of the numQuotesReceived it will
    // not break the compiled form of this code
    fireTableCellUpdated((R) this, QuoteMonitorTableModel..numQuotesReceived);
}
```

If you think this feature wouldn't open up a world of possibilities for useful programming tools, you're lacking imagination ;)

Comment: I don't think that last line is syntactically correct.  That's one reason.

Comment: For one thing, because `field` and `method` aren't, and should not be, keywords.

Comment: @tieTYT if you're referring to A.foo(int).method, I know this is not normal Java syntax, but this is a possible syntax for identifying the method.  If you're referring to A.getMethod("foo", int.class), int.class actually is valid Java.

Comment: Because they're common & useful variable names.

Comment: @SLaks haha, fair point!

Answer (score 8):

It would be difficult to introduce keywords in Java, however you can introduce new symbol combinations.  For example in Java 8 you can write

```
 MyClass::myMethod
```

To get a [Method Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html), something you can't do in Java 7.

You could do something similar with fields and there have been suggestions to support property references.

You can even write

```
 HashSet<String>::new
```

to get a reference to a constructor ALA `new HashSet<String>()`

You can turn a Method into a MethodHandle with [MethodHandles.Lookup.unreflect(Method)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles.Lookup.html#unreflect%28java.lang.reflect.Method%29)  and you can turn a Constructor into a MethodHandle with [MethodHandles.Lookup.unreflectConstructor(Constructor)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles.Lookup.html#unreflectConstructor%28java.lang.reflect.Constructor%29)

Once you have a MethodHandle you can set an object for it to call on.

Comment: This isn't useful. It's called a method reference, but it has nothing to do with a `Method` object. Similarly `::new` has nothing to do with a `Constructor` object.

Comment: Oh wow, that's exactly what I was looking for!  Except do you know if you can specify parameter types to select an overloaded method?  I can't find anything off the bat from a Google search...

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis  It's like says that Plain IO and NIO have nothing to do with another. If you look closely enough, you are right but you can unwrap() a Method into a MethodHandle and curry the MethodHandle to add parameters are change their order/type etc.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Please clarify how you can get from `MyClass::myMethod` to a `Method` object which is what the OP is asking about.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Unless the OP has to use a Method due to an API he is using, I would assume he wants the functionality described. You can go from a Method to a MethodHandle.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I am looking to get a `Method` object or something like it I can use for reflection like `getName()`, `getParameterTypes()` etc.

Comment: This `Method fooMethod = A.getMethod("foo");` is the functionality OP wants. How do you get that with a method reference?

Comment: `A::foo` will give you "something like it"  BTW You can use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles.Lookup.html#findGetter(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class) to turn a field into a MethodHandle.

Comment: I don't think you understand. A method reference is a special notation. It does not resolve to an object reference. You cannot do `Object o = SomeClass::someMethod;`. There is no way to go from a method reference to a `Method` object. At least, not as far as I know.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Interesting. Though like I said, I don't think the OP needs a `Method` object.

Comment: Where does your assumption that they need a method reference come from? Especially when they've specifically stated `Method fooMethod = A.getMethod("foo");`.

Comment: I'm still waiting for a reply :).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis "A.class has a distinct advantage over Class.forName("A"): it will still work if the name of A is changed by refactoring or obfuscation.

However, there is no way to get this advantage with fields and methods.  --- How about this syntax --- A..foo();"

Comment: That's a good point. However, the fact that the expression `A.class` produces a `Class` object is fundamentally different than a method reference. Only the compiler can makes use of a method reference. The developer can't. If you already know that a method exists, there is no point validating it at compile time with a method reference.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Everything you say is true, but I was attempting to read between the lines as to what the OP was trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a few reasons:

1. `Method fooIntMethod = A.foo(int).method;` is syntactically incorrect
2. `Field xField = A.x.field;` now you can't have a field in the `x` class named "field".  What if people already had this in their code?  This would not be backwards compatible.
3. Same thing applies to `A.foo().method`.  What if the response already had a field named `method`?

Comment: 1: Wrong; `int` is a keyword.  (that would be right for non-keyword types)

Comment: 2,3: For this syntax to make sense, `field` and `method` would need to be keywords, which would be a dumb idea.

Comment: That's not an objection; he's explicitly asking for new syntax.

Comment: you forgot 4. The JLS :)

Comment: Duh, that's a good point about what if A.x has a field named "field" or A.foo() returns something with a field named "method".

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible and would be very difficult to implement with those keywords.

The expression

```
SomeClass.class
```

is known as a *class literal* and returns a `Class` object. [This is described in the Java Language Specification.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.2)

Assuming in

```
Field xField = A.x.field;
```

`A` is a variable of type `Class`, it wouldn't make sense because the `Class` class doesn't have a visible field called `x`.

Assuming `A` was the actual class, again it wouldn't make sense because the class `A` wouldn't necessarily have a `static` field named `x`. If it did, you would be accessing the variable itself, not its corresponding `Field` object.

Now adding the `field` keyword to

```
A.x.field;
```

would not work with instance fields since you can't access them from a `static` context.

Same reasoning for methods.

A lot would need to be changed. `.class` can be used with names of classes/interfaces/enums or primitives. What would `.field` or `.method` be used with? It looks to me like it would break the syntax for variable access and method invocation.

Comment: I agree, that it would be difficult to implement. But either something is "not possible" OR something is "difficult to implement"...

Comment: @Balder I guess it would be hard to prove that it is not possible. I'll change my wording.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I proposed a different syntax in an edit at the bottom of my original question, what do you think of it?

Comment: @Andork I don't find it pretty and I feel like it could possibly cause bugs. If you had a `static` method `foo`, would `A..foo()` be a `Method` reference or a typo where the user actually wanted to invoke the method? That's a problem I see, but you can always try the Java developer's mailing list. I think they can give you a legit answer.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Well, basically it's just a matter of thinking up a good operator right?  The best other possibility I can think of is .:  (:: is out, : would cause awkward conflicts with the conditional operator...)

Comment: @Andork For methods, I think it's harder because you'd have to pass the parameter types. With the `Class#getMethod` method, you can pass `Class` arguments. How would you do that with any other notation?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Well just look at the way method signatures are named in some places.  For example, in Javadocs: `@see java.lang.Class#getMethod(String, Class[])`.  A comma-separated list of type names would be easy for the compiler to interpret.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis it would add grammar rules to the JLS for sure, but I don't think it would be a huge change.

Comment: @Andork So something like `A..someMethod(String.class, Foo.class, Bar.class)` rather then `A.class.getMethod(String.class, Foo.class, Bar.class)`?

Comment: @Andork Another issue is that `getMethod` returns public methods. You need `getDeclaredMethod()` for other access modifiers. What do you do with that?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I don't think .class is necessary.  The compiler could transform `A..someMethod(String, Foo, Bar)` into the equivalent of `A.class.getDeclaredMethod("someMethod", String.class, Foo.class, Bar.class)` in the bytecode.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis the advantage of the new syntax is that the compiler would produce a compile-time error if such a method does not exist.

Comment: @Andork In this case, I don't see why you would need compile time checking. If you know it has the method, just invoke it. Why go through reflection?

Comment: @Andork Still, the syntax seems messy and a mix of too many other types of notations.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis you just haven't seen any of the many cases in which it would be useful.  I'll put an example in my original question.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I also wanted to add two things: 1) getting an instance Field via A..x would be possible in a static context, because getDeclaredField(...) can get instance Fields.  2) Visibility rules would be enforced; A..x will produce an error wherever A.x will produce an error (so classes will still be able to use the .. operator on their own private fields and methods, just not each others').